# How to Getting Buttons inside Tabs of WPF Ribbon not selected

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon, findcontrol

We are making a change in our main screen, and we're using WPF. The main window contains 6 tabs, and into each tab, some buttons. When the application starts, it verifies which screen (openned by each button), the user is allowed to open. If user can't open one of those windows, the button corresponding to that screen will be disabled and the icon will change. Our problem is, this method i've made only applies this change into the selected tab.

Code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Encontra todos os objetos na tela
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="objetoTela"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject objetoTela) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (objetoTela != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(objetoTela); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject objetoFilho = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(objetoTela, i);
            if (objetoFilho != null && objetoFilho is T)
            {
                yield return (T)objetoFilho;
            }

            foreach (T componenteObjetoFilho in FindVisualChildren<T>(objetoFilho))
            {
                yield return componenteObjetoFilho;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method, FindVisualChildren(), search into our window for a specified type. You can see that here:

```
foreach (RibbonTab tab in FindVisualChildren<RibbonTab>(this.Ribbon))
```

Code:

```
foreach (MenuResources item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MenuResources)))
                {
                   foreach (RibbonTab tab in FindVisualChildren<RibbonTab>(this.Ribbon))
                    {
                        foreach (RibbonButton button in FindVisualChildren<RibbonButton>(tab))
                        {
                            if (button.Name.Equals("rbb" + item.ToString()))
                            {
                                if (authorizationService.CheckAccess((Int64)item, true))
                                {
                                    button.LargeImageSource = (ImageSource)FindResource("ImageMenu" + item.ToString());
                                    button.IsEnabled = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    button.LargeImageSource = (ImageSource)FindResource("ImageMenuDesabilitado" + item.ToString());
                                    button.IsEnabled = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This is our RibbonTabs (as example, no button here, just the tabs):

```
<ribbon:RibbonTab x:Name="rbtOperacaoLCG" ContextualTabGroupHeader="Operação" Header="LCG" BorderBrush="White" KeyTip="O" Foreground="Black" Background="White"/>
<ribbon:RibbonTab x:Name="rbtSeguranca"  Header="Segurança" KeyTip="S" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal"/>
<ribbon:RibbonTab x:Name="rbtManutencao" Header="Manutenção" KeyTip="M" Foreground="Black"/>
<ribbon:RibbonTab x:Name="rbtComunicacao" Header="Comunicação" KeyTip="C" Foreground="Black" />
<ribbon:RibbonTab x:Name="rbtOperacaoComum" ContextualTabGroupHeader="Operação" Header="Comum" BorderBrush="White" KeyTip="O" Foreground="Black" Background="White" IsSelected="True"/>
<ribbon:RibbonTab x:Name="rbtOperacaoLTQ" ContextualTabGroupHeader="Operação" Header="LTQ" BorderBrush="White" KeyTip="O" Foreground="Black" Background="White"/>
```

So, this is our problem. How i can get all RibbonButtons of all RibbonTabs into our Main Window?

Best regards,

Gustavo

Comment: Have you tried searching LogicalTree? VisualTree will be empty if the tab is closed, as far as I remember.

Comment: No, it's not empty. When i debug the Ribbon component, all buttons are instantiated.

Comment: So you have the button instances and you disabled them, and they are not disabled? If that is the case, check commands that you bound to your buttons. You will need to set CanExecute to false.

Comment: I think you didn't understood. I have 6 tabs on my Ribbon. The tab i'm seeing, all buttons disable when user logins (those he can access), but on those other tabs, they don't change (because those tabs are hidden, i mean, not selected).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you pass "this" into the second FindVisualChildren call? (FindVisualChildren(this)). Have you tried to pass "tab" instead?:

```
foreach (RibbonTab tab in FindVisualChildren<RibbonTab>(this.Ribbon))
{ 
    foreach (RibbonButton button in FindVisualChildren<RibbonButton>(tab))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, and tried 2 cases

1. `FindVisualChildren<RibbonButton>(tab)` -> starting point tab -> result 0
2. `FindVisualChildren<RibbonButton>(window)` -> starting point window got buttons only from main tab

I need a button from specific tab so I wrote following (is using "Items" property of Tab) ... be aware that I'm checking only buttons in "RibbonGroups" so is kind of specific solution but you can get a point how to get it.

```
        protected Button GetDeleteButton(Window window, string tabName){
            var tab = FindVisualChildren<RibbonTab>(window).FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == tabName);
            if (tab == null){
                return null;
            }
            var groups = tab.Items.Cast<object>().Where(n => n is RibbonGroup).Cast<RibbonGroup>();

            foreach (var group in groups){
                var buts = group.Items.Cast<object>().Where(n => n is RibbonButton).Cast<RibbonButton>();
                var myButton = buts.FirstOrDefault(n => (string)n.Tag == "Delete");
                if (myButton != null){
                    return myButton;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject {
            if (depObj != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++) {
                    DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                    if (child != null && child is T) {
                        yield return (T)child;
                    }

                    foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child)) {
                        yield return childOfChild;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope helps